# How can I changing shared photo options from gallery in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have sharing intent. Users can share image, video and text from another apps. I do not want user to select more than 10 images from user's photo gallery.

I've writed this function (sharedMessagesControl) inside ShareActivity but I want to check it another practical solution. How can I check this before the activity screen opens? Is there a way to control this while on the photo gallery screen? How can I do this?

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".share.ShareActivity"
            android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />   
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Here is method:

```
ShareActivity(){

    private void sharedMessagesControl() {

    sharedIntent = getIntent();

    try {
        if ((sharedIntent != null) && (sharedIntent.getType() != null) &&
                ((sharedIntent.getPackage() == null) || (!sharedIntent.getPackage().equals(getPackageName())))) {

            String receivedType = sharedIntent.getType();
            String action = sharedIntent.getAction();

            if (action != null && (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) || action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"))) {

                ArrayList<Uri> uris = sharedIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

                if (uris != null && receivedType.contains("image/")) {

                    if (uris.size() > MAX_IMAGE_MEDIA_LIMIT) {

                        sharedIntent = null;
                        new MyToast(R.string.max_limit_image, MyToast.Length.Short);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Mylog.printStackTrace(TAG + " shareMessageControl error ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does check it through intent mean?

Comment: another practical solution. please look my edited answer

Comment: I dont get your problem means you want to check whether there are more than 10 images in the gallery before the intent of gallery actually opens?

Comment: yes exactly ...

Comment: what if I provide you the algorithm for it ? Can you convert that algorithm to code yourself?

Comment: I solved this and writed below. But if you have another solution please can you write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that control it from ShareActivity's onCreate method.

```
public class ShareActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int count) {

     if (!sharedMessageControl()) {
         finishAffinity();
         }
         setContentView(R.layout.share_activity);
         }
     }

        private boolean sharedMessageControl() {

            sharedIntent = getIntent();

            try {
                if ((sharedIntent != null) && (sharedIntent.getType() != null) &&
                        ((sharedIntent.getPackage() == null) || (!sharedIntent.getPackage().equals(getPackageName())))) {

                    String receivedType = sharedIntent.getType();
                    String action = sharedIntent.getAction();

                    if (action != null && (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) || action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"))) {

                        ArrayList<Uri> uris = sharedIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

                        if (uris != null && receivedType.contains("image/")) {

                            if (uris.size() > MAX_IMAGE_MEDIA_LIMIT) {

                                sharedIntent = null;
                                new MyToast(R.string.max_limit_image, MyToast.Length.Long);

                                return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }//image

                    }
                }

                return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Mylog.printStackTrace(TAG + " sharedMessageControl error ", e);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) for how to receive data from other apps. And you need to handle separate :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

for all different types of data.

Comment: Thanks, i know these and i can get intents but my question is different

Comment: Is there a way to control this while on the photo gallery screen?

Comment: if you can first open your app splash screen and then after gallery screen then it is possible check type of data. Because it is always possible in an activity.

Comment: actually i don't want to opening app

Comment: I solved this and writed below. But if you have another solution please can you write?